# How do I create an initialized array of a size defined by a register in assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm

I am currently trying to initialize an array in assembly, with a size defined by the number in a register. I am also using NASM, and compiling for 32 bit.

I have already tried using times to define a number of bytes, but it doesn't work because times expects a constant, rather than a register.

```
mov bl, bh
mul bl, 512
sectors times bl db 0
```

bh is an input register for the function I am making in which this is being used.

When assembling, NASM outputs an error:

error: non-constant argument supplied to TIMES

Does anyone know how I can create an array of 0s using the register as the size?

EDIT: I have decided to write data directly to memory, rather than initializing it with times.

EDIT 2: Here is the driver I have written: https://pastebin.com/JKdUaeH5

Comment: `times <size> db` is static storage, which is always fixed size.  If you want runtime-variable allocation, you need a way to get more memory pages from the OS (e.g. `mmap` or `brk` on POSIX, VirtualAlloc on Windows).  Or if your code is freestanding, you have to write a memory manager yourself.  Or simply reserve some stack space.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think what I will do for now is remove the need for the register and just load a whole lot of sectors since the kernel that I am loading with this won't execute the extra empty sectors. This is for the same project I was working on in the other question I asked, but I moved away from loading the second part with C and am now using assembly instead since I have direct access to the memory, and because the idea I had was kind of silly and the code was messy.

Comment: If this is for a bootloader, sounds like you should find the size of your kernel, then build the bootloader with `nasm -DKERNEL_SIZE=1234` or whatever.  Also, if you're loading a kernel, you don't need to `db` that memory, just use space outside of the 512B that the BIOS loads.  If you used `sectors times 512*12 db 0`, your bootloader would obviously not still fit in 512 bytes.

Comment: @PeterCordes I suppose it wouldn't fit. I'm actually using a two-stage bootloader but I think I want to load the bytes that I read directly into memory. What instructions should I use to load the bytes into memory as I read them? I assume there is an instruction to put bytes into a specified memory address right?

Comment: Read them from disk?  If you're using BIOS calls to read the disk, you pass it a disk location and a memory address.  It copies from disk to memory.  Then your data is just sitting there waiting for you to read it with loads/stores, or jump to it with `jmp` to get the CPU to fetch it as code.  Google an example bootloader, or look in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for some of the links to Michael Petch's answer here on SO.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am not using BIOS calls to read the disk, I'm in 32 bit protected mode because my kernel was too big to fit in memory, at least where I put it. I'm writing an assembly disk driver so the kernel will fit into memory again. I was thinking that ```mov [ebx], al``` would work to write into memory, where ebx holds a memory address like 0xEFFFFF (about 15 MB right?) and al is the data. Sorry I sent it early, I pressed enter by accident

Comment: Normally you'd load your whole kernel with legacy BIOS calls *before* switching to 32-bit protected mode, *then* jump to it.  Unless your kernel is so big that it doesn't fit in the 640kB of lowmem?  But yes, in protected mode with a flat memory model, and segment limits set high enough, yes you can just use `mov [reg], reg` to store wherever you want.  With paging disabled, addresses are still physical.  Or more complex but faster, program the hard drive controller to DMA your data to into place instead of reading it a byte at a time.

Comment: @PeterCordes It would probably fit in the lower memory but I want to switch to 32-bit mode now so I don't have to worry about it later if I ever make it that big. Also thanks for the help!

Comment: @PeterCordes actually, I have one more question: Memory is addressed byte by byte right? So if I wrote a word to memory I should increment my memory index by two?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Or in 32-bit mode, you would normally want to copy dwords and increment by 4.  Or use `rep movsd`.

Comment: @PeterCordes The hard drive driver reads one word at a time, so unless it actually matters (I'm pretty sure it doesn't, since its basically the same thing, just at a bigger scale), I'm just going to leave it as is. I can link the driver I have if you want to read it (you probably don't though).